# Perl with Selenium: cannot save the Web page with Ctrl+S

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to download an entire HTML from the given URL with Perl Selenium::Chrome.
My scheme is:

- open the Web page
- press Ctrl+S to open the Save As box
- press Alt+S to accept the default file location / name and save it

I ran the code attached below but I cannot save it.
When I tried "no headless" mode (visible mode), I found:

- the browser opened specified Web page
- no save box opened
- no save action was done
- closed safely without errors nor saved files

How can I make it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# seleniumTest.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
use Data::Dumper;
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::ActionChains;

my $url = 'https://www.example.com/foo';
my $profile_path = '/home/cf/.config/google-chrome'; # this is to use my own google account info
my $profile_name = 'Profile 1'; # ditto

my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new (
    extra_capabilities => {
    'goog:chromeOptions' => {
        args => ['user-data-dir='.$profile_path, 'profile-directory='.$profile_name,
             #   'headless', 'disable-gpu', 'window-size=1920,1080', 'no-sandbox' # if you want to do it headless, decomment this line
        ],
        #binary => '/mnt/c/Users/cf/Downloads/chrome-headless-shell-linux64/chrome-headless-shell' # ditto
    }
    }
    );

$driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(5000);

$driver->get($url); # the browser opens if you don't set the headless mode

warn $driver->get_title(); # This works fine so I believe the selenium works

sleep 10;
warn "opened";
my $html = $driver->find_element("/html");

my $action_chains = Selenium::ActionChains->new(driver => $driver);
$action_chains->key_down( [ KEYS->{'control'}], $html); # I am not sure that it is ok to specify <html> as the element...
$action_chains->send_keys('s');
$action_chains->key_up( [ KEYS->{'control'}], $html);
sleep 10;
warn "try to save";

$action_chains->key_down( [ KEYS->{'alt'}], $html);
$action_chains->send_keys('s');
$action_chains->key_up( [ KEYS->{'alt'}], $html);
warn "saved?";
sleep 10;
$driver->shutdown_binary;
warn "ended";
```

Comment: I suspect that Selenium::Chrome can only communicate with the browser engine, not with the browser chrome, which is what the "save" dialog is a part of. That being said, if all you want is the page source, you could try the `get_page_source()` method on the Selenium::Chrome object? Alternately, you might want to look at `HTTP::Tiny`, if all you need is to load a page and retrieve the source...

Comment: I have tried get_page_source() and UserAgent module but both failed maybe due to the target site's restriction. I could successfully capture the pages with the Excel VBA RPA macro but it takes the computer's control. So I wanted to try the selenium headless browser...

Comment: One possibility that I've run into in the past is that sometimes it takes time for the browser to render the page? If you introduce a pause of a few seconds between navigating to the page and trying to get the source, does that help? Another possibility is that the page is entirely rendered in client-side Javascript, and thus the "source" may not be available to Selenium for some weird reason. I'm not sure what to do in that case. If you were on a Mac, at a certain point I'd say to use AppleScript, but I don't know what the equivalent on Windows or Linux would be.